# Remove window.onresize when changing angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onresize

I have a single page app that utilizes ui-router where list page use listController and detail page use detailController.
Detail page has `window.onresize` event attached while list page doesn't.
The problem is whenever I move from detail page to list page, the onresize event still listen and throw error about the resize target element doesn't exist.

How to remove the window.onresize event listener when I'm changing page?

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('listController', function() {
            // do things for list page
        })
        .controller('detailController', function() {
            window.onresize = function() {
                // do some resize function
            }
        })
})();
```

Comment: Maybe simply set `window.onresize` to `null` or a new/empty function in the `listController`?

Comment: It's a bad idea I suppose, since there'll be more pages added along with the controllers. I don't want to add such redundancy to all controllers.

Comment: Then you can do it on the view unload, but i didn't think of that in time, it's in the answer below, just add the function Rob Glass suggested on the same scope (controller) where you set the `window.onresize`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reset the onresize function once the route is navigated away from and the controller instance is destroyed.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   window.onresize = null
}
```

Comment: Of course! Why didn't I think about searching with 'function to run when leaving controller'?!  Good enough it works!